# no notification for automatic upload of images and videos in google+

Tags: notifications, google-plus

How can I configure my 2.3.5 phone so that I don't get a notification for automatic upload of images and videos in google+?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about when your phone uploads to Google+ automatically using the built-in Instant Upload, then you can just switch that off in the Google+ notifications. In fact I think that you must have switched that on at some point because I'm sure it was off by default for me.

Open the Google+ app, press <kbd>Menu</kbd>, select **Settings**, press **Notification Settings**, and then scroll down to the **Photos** category and take the tick out of "Photos added from Instant Upload". You'll still get the red notification box at the top inside the Google+ app, but won't get notified in the standard Android notifications bar any more. The other notification settings are there too, if you want to tune any of the others.